# Google Collab shows RunTime disconnected On running Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I a running a ML Code of Decision Tree on a Binary Data of size (2700000x7), but when I run it Google Collab crashed and shows runtime disconnected after about 3 hours. The RAM Utilization is only 3GB.

Tried to Reduce the dataset size to (100000x7) and it is working but crashes above it.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Google Collab has RAM limits and Disk limits.
It is possible that you are growing the decision tree too deep which takes a lot of memory.

Try changing the max_depth parameter.

Another possibility may be that the algorithm uses some extra memory (saving subsets of data for instance).

Please add more information if my answer didn't solve it.

Comment: Hey Ive mentioned the RAM utilization does not go over 3GB RAM and the Disk utilization 12.4GB out of 82GB. And no Subsets are being saved. The Hyperparameters are the base ones given.

Comment: The base hyperparameters in sklearn will grow the tree until each sample is in a leaf.  Try changing the max_depth and see if it solves the issue as I suggested